# print text from while loop on a single line in python

Tags: python

I made a decryption .py file for fun but while decrypting, the text is displayed vertically.  My current code is:

```
while depthTracker >= 0:
    depthTracker -= 1
    multiplier = 32 ** depthTracker
    letter = userIn
    letter = letter // multiplier
    userIn -= letter * multiplier
    letterPrint(letter)
```

In this code, each letter is decrypted one at a time and is displayed with my def function `def letterPrint(nb):` which prints the correct letter according to a number.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your code and accurately describe the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In letterPrint , where you are printing, do

```
print('whaterver you want to print',end = ' ')
```

Answer (score 2):

If you leave a dangling comma at the end of your **print** command in **letterPrint**, the system routine will not start a new line.  I can't comment on your actual code, since you failed to provide it.  However, it might look something like this:

```
print letter,
```

Note that trailing comma.

Answer (score 1):

What version of python?

If it's 2.7 I think you can change the print statement in `letterPrint` to the following:

```
print str,
```

If it's 3.0 I think you can do this equivalently:

```
print(str, end=" ")
```

Is this the behaviour you want?

```
Python 2.7 (r27:82525, Jul  4 2010, 07:43:08) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
i = 1
while i < 5:
    print "hi",
    i = i + 1

> hi hi hi hi
```